# How to run SQL codes saved in a .txt file via Unix

Tags: sql-server, unix

I'm totally new to this as I just changed my job and the new job is using Unix a lot. So my question is, if I save my SQL code into a .txt file (with temp tables and variables, etc.), how do I run it within Unix?

I searched the internet and looks like the resources are limited and too advanced for me to read... Not sure if I need to connect to MS SQL Server first.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: could you move the code from the text file into a scripting language like python/php and try to run the queries that way ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As I mentioned I'm totally new to this and just started to learn some basic unix code, not to mention Python. It's something I would love to learn as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u user -p pass < command.sql
```

Like described in the mysql documentation on ubuntuusers http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/MySQL/Backup